# Build and run a project from VS extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I'm working on a Visual Studio 2015 extension which add a menu item when right-clicking on some items in the solution explorer. I want to build and run a specific project from the solution when my menu item is clicked.

I know how to find my project as a `EnvDTE.Project` from `ApplicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects`. I could then take its `FullName` property and build, either through running `MSBuild.exe` directly, or through [BuildManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager) class. However, this will probably not integrate build results into Visual Studio - progress, error list etc.

**Question:** Is there an API that builds a `EnvDTE.Project` directly?

Answer (score 0):

[SolutionBuild.BuildProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionbuild.buildproject).

Pro over [BuildManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager) - supposed to be better integrated into Visual Studio UI.

Con: Less control and details - for example, you can't set custom properties, or get resulting outputs (for example `TargetOutput` ItemGroup, which points to the resulting binary).